# MySQL: How to set a local variable using select in a stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

It seems like this must be a dumb question :) but I can't seem to find it posted any where.

I need to set a number of local variables in a sproc from a select statement.

This works from the query window:

```
select  @value1 := value1, @value2 := value2 from test_table limit 1; 
select  @value1, @value2;
```

But when I try and do a similar thing in a stored procedure, I get: 
SQL Error (1064):You have an error in your SQL syntax...

```
BEGIN

    declare p_value1 varchar(50); 
    declare p_value2 varchar(50); 
    select  p_value1 := value1, p_value2 := value2 from test_table limit 1; 

END
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you include a `DELIMITER $$` (or similar) statement before your procedure?

Comment: In SQL, isn’t assignment just a regular = sign (no : symbol)

Comment: Yes - it wasn't an issue with declaring the sproc. The answer below did the trick. BTW the := does work from the query window. I'm used to SQL Server - what works in the query window works in a sproc but not true with MySQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [SELECT...INTO syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html):

```
BEGIN

    declare p_value1 varchar(50); 
    declare p_value2 varchar(50); 
    select value1, value2 into p_value1, p_value2 from test_table limit 1; 

END
```

Comment: Hey thanks! I'm used to SQL Server - this is a bit different.

Comment: Yeah, MySQL is totally different. You really need to make yourself at home in their reference documentation. I've been using MySQL for many years, and I open their doc daily.